# any alternative deduction to class template argument deduction?

Tags: c++, template-argument-deduction, ctad, deduction-guide

I have a class template:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
class iterator
{
  explicit iterator(T*);
};
```

I tried using the c++17 feature `Class template argument deduction (CTAD)` to deduce `T`, but I can't do so, since there is no way to deduce `N` and specifying `N` means CTAD will not be attempted anyway. So I went the old-fashioned way:

```
template <std::size_t N, typename T>
auto make_iterator(T* const p)
{
  return iterator<T, N>(p);
}
```

This allows me to only provide `N` and `T` is deduced. Is there a c++20 (and beyond) feature I overlooked, that would allow me to dispense with this function? I tried this:

```
template <std::size_t N, typename T>
iterator(T*) -> iterator<T, N>;
```

But, it doesn't work, as:

> Class template argument deduction is only performed if no template
> argument list is present. If a template argument list is specified,
> deduction does not take place.

Comment: AFAK, partial specialization of CTAD was rejected.

Comment: I don't think CTAD was even attempted. As soon as you specify a template argument, it is not tried AFAIK.

Comment: The `make_*` function is as good as it gets, really.

Comment: I thought maybe I missed some trick or something.